# python/gtk3 set modal window issue

Tags: python, gtk3

i have an application that has two `Gtk.Window`'s and one of them calls the another, but when using `Gtk.Window.set_modal(True)` it doesn't work, i still can interact with the main window...

any help?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the second as a parent from the first too.

```
window2.set_transient_for(window1)
window2.set_modal(True)
```

Comment: got `TypeError: Expected Gtk.Window, but got GObjectMeta` while doing this...

Comment: You need to pass the instance from the first window to the constructor of the second one. I think that traceback tells you, you used an uninitialized `Gtk.Window`.